# find shortest path sequences between subset of vertices

Tags: r, igraph, lapply, shortest-path, do.call

I have a network `net` and a `df` with origin-destination relations `od`. The vertices of`od` are part of `net`. Now I want to find the `shortest_path` sequences between the vertices in `od`.

I know how to find the `shortest_path` sequences between all vertices of `net`. I tried to subset the vertices of `net` as `od` is a subset of `net`.

A sample:

```
data <- data.frame(from  =c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1),
                   to    =c(4,  3,  4,  5,  6,  5),
                   weight=c(0.2,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.2))

net <- graph.data.frame(data, directed=FALSE)

od<-data[1:3,]

results <- do.call(c,
                   lapply(V(net)[od[,1]], function(v) shortest_paths(net,v,to=V(net)[setdiff(od[,2],v)],output="epath")$epath))

results
```

actual result is a list of 24 edge sequences. Desired output would be a list of 3 edge sequences:
from 1 to 4
from 2 to 3
from 3 to 4

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but did you intend to write `od <- data[1:3,]` and `v` instead of `x` inside your anonymous function?

Comment: Oh yes. Edited it.

Comment: Does this line work:

`sapply(1:nrow(od), function(v) shortest_paths(net, od$from[v], od$to[v], output = "epath")$epath)` ?

Comment: perfect! thank you!

Comment: @BenNutzer  Could you write up a short answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Writing my comment down as an answer.

This can be achieved by iterating (`sapply`) along the number of rows of the given dataset `od`, while trying to stay as close as possible to the original approach:

```
sapply(1:nrow(od), function(v) shortest_paths(net, od$from[v], od$to[v], output = "epath")$epath)
```

The result is the desired edge sequence.